# Which is the best sentence?

Tags: grammar

Between the three sentences, which is better, and also, are all three grammatically correct?

1. 我把地图放在房间。
2. 我放地图在房间。
3. 我在房间放地图。

Comment: How about giving us your opinion first? That way you would learn better?

Comment: Well , i came across the first sentence , but if i have to be asked i would choose the third but i think is because i'm not too familiarized with the 把 construction.

Comment: If only @zerox is a bit patient and waited for your attempt before answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 feels awkward to me, it seems to be a verbatim translation from English "I put the map in the room", otherwise I think it's the same as 1.

Difference between 1 and 3 may depend on the context:

- 1 is to answer: Where do you put the map?
- 3 is to answer: What do you put in the room?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my poor English.

well, Abously stence No.1 would be considered as most popourate.But grammatically speacking all these three stences could count in daily lives.They are different merely  in the way of fousing.In the first sentence you try to describe the action, while the other two is mainly about underlineing the place(room for No.3) and the abject(map for No.2).

By the way,if you try to make the whole thing puts together and not so awkward.You might just need to add a little bit of modal words in it.Like "我把地图放在了房间里" or "我在房间里放了地图".